# How to get the instance of a previously created Google Chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have a Web App which uses Google Charts.
There are more than one chart on a page.
I successfully create and render the charts.

Depending on the user's filters, I receive new chart data via Ajax.
How can I reacquire a chart object and update it, if I don't keep the returned object that far in the code?

I wonna do something similar to the following:

```js
function DrawChart()
{
  // Code code code ... more code

  // Initialize
  var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById("my-chart-div"));
  // Draw
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

And later on:

```js
function UserDidSomething()
{
    var newData = MyAjaxCall(...);
    var options = ...;
                             
    var chart = ...; // What goes here??
                             
    chart.draw(newData, options);
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Shy.

Comment: You could have your `DrawChart` function just return the `chart` object so that you can store the reference for later.

Comment: Did something similar...
Will put the code example as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a dynamic `charts` object that keeps the created charts:

```js
/// <summary>
/// This object holds created charts in order to edit them.
/// The key for the chart is the div id (e.g. charts["chart-my-chartname"]).
/// </summary>
var charts = {};

function ChartCreated(divId)
{
    return charts[divId] !== undefined && charts[divId] != null;
}

function GetChart(divId)
{
    return charts[divId];
}

function AddChart(divId, chart)
{
    charts[divId] = chart;
}

function RemoveChart(divId)
{
    charts[divId] = null;
}

function CreateOrUpdateChart(divId, chartType, data, options)
{
    var chart;

    // If the chart was previously created, use its object
    if (ChartCreated(divId))
    {
        chart = GetChart(divId);
    }
    else // If there was no chart, create and keep it
    {
        chart = InitializeNewChart(chartType, divId);
        AddChart(divId, chart);
    }

    // Create a new DataTable object using the JavaScript Literal Initializer, and the received JSON data object
    data = new google.visualization.DataTable(data);

    // Render chart
    chart.draw(data, options);
}

function InitializeNewChart(type, divId)
{
    var container = document.getElementById(divId);

    switch (type)
    {
        case "Scatter": return new google.visualization.ScatterChart(container);
        case "Column": return new google.visualization.ColumnChart(container);
        case "Line": return new google.visualization.LineChart(container);
        default: return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: It returns me this error :--  Cannot read property 'ColumnChart' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'ColumnChart' of undefined

Comment: You probably didn't load the `visualization` library. See this doc: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries